# Record set always closed. VB Excel returning data from stored procedure as record set

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I keep getting this error when running in Excel vb.

> Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

I can execute the stored procedure in SSMS and return good data. I can also run a simple string query in Excel vb and return data fine. What would cause the record set to close?

I have tried manually stringing up the query in VB and it's the same error result. Once I did that I printed and copied the vb query and pasted it in to SQL query and it returned data fine.

```
Sub ExecuteStoredProcedureAndRetrieveData()
    Dim conn As Object
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.ConnectionString = ""
    conn.Open

    Dim cmd As Object
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "ProcedureStored"

    Dim rs As Object
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.Open cmd

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cmd.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

This is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcedureStored
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @day_date DATE = '1973-12-25';
    DECLARE @date_start DATETIME;
    DECLARE @date_end DATETIME;

    SET @date_start = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @day_date) + ' 06:00:00' AS DATETIME);
    SET @date_end = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @day_date) + ' 16:30:00' AS DATETIME);

    DECLARE @Hours TABLE (Date DATETIME, Hour INT);
    DECLARE @i INT;
    DECLARE @j INT;
    DECLARE @loop_count INT;
    DECLARE @date_change_flag INT;

    SET @i = CONVERT(INT, DATEPART(HOUR, @date_start));
    SET @j = CONVERT(INT, DATEPART(HOUR, @date_end));
    SET @loop_count = 0;
    SET @date_change_flag = 0;

    WHILE @loop_count < 11
    BEGIN
        IF @i < 24 AND @date_change_flag = 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Hours
            VALUES (@date_start, @i);
        END
        ELSE IF @i >= 24 AND @date_change_flag = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @date_change_flag = 1;
            SET @i = 0;

            INSERT INTO @Hours
            VALUES (DATEADD(DAY, 1, @date_start), @i);
        END
        ELSE IF @date_change_flag = 1
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Hours
            VALUES (DATEADD(DAY, 1, @date_start), @i);
        END

        SET @loop_count = @loop_count + 1;
        SET @i = @i + 1;
    END

    SELECT 'ID 19' AS [ID], [Date], [Hour],
           SUM(ISNULL([Errors (Delays)], 0)) AS [Errors (Delays)]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 'ID' AS [ID], FORMAT([time_stamp], 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS [Date], DATEPART(HOUR, [time_stamp]) AS [Hour], COUNT(*) AS [Errors (Delays)]
        FROM [error_events]
        WHERE [error_type] = 0 AND [time_stamp] BETWEEN @date_start AND @date_end
          AND [source] LIKE '%Filter1%'
          AND ([trace_path] LIKE '%/Filter2%' 
               OR [trace_path] LIKE '%/Filter3%' 
               OR [trace_path] LIKE '%/Filter4%' 
               OR [trace_path] LIKE '%/Filter5%')
        GROUP BY FORMAT([time_stamp], 'yyyy-MM-dd'), DATEPART(HOUR, [time_stamp])
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ID' AS [ID], FORMAT(DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS [Date], Hour AS [Hour], NULL
        FROM @Hours
    ) AS Data
    GROUP BY [Date], [Hour]
    ORDER BY [ID];
END
```

Comment: So, which row generates the error? Your connectionstring is empty as well

Comment: I copied your VBA and SQL but substituted my own Select statement and could not duplicate your error.  This would suggest the problem is in your SELECT statement.  You might use "Set rs=cmd.Execute" instead of "rs.open cmd" and also remove "rs.close".  This might give you a better error.  The error may be when you try to close a recordset that was never successfully opened.  Set a breakpoint to determine which line in VBA is giving you this error.

Comment: @AaronBertrand adding SET NOCOUNT ON; did the trick. It runs in all fashions now.

Comment: Shouldn't your `ConnectionString` have details of the connection?  [Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ole-db-driver-for-sql-server/)